# jquery Animate issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have got a weird problem here, and more interesting that  it works fine on jquery version  1.5.2 and doesn't on version 1.4.3.

So, I am going to drop a piece of the code here:

```
$('.slides .items').animate({
    left: number + 'px'
}, 500, 'swing');
```

Here is an item of the HTML:

```
   <div class = 'slides'>

                <div class = 'items'>

                    <div class = 'item' style = 'background: url(img/slides/slide-1919.jpg) no-repeat;'>

                        <div class = 'nav'>
                            <div class = 'back link' onclick = 'changeSlide(-1);'></div>
                            <div class = 'forward link' onclick = 'changeSlide(1);'></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class = 'title'><span class = 'textBuffer'>1919</span></div>

                        <div class = 'contentTitle'><span class = 'textBuffer'>The first Loblaw <em>Groceterias</em> store opens in Toronto</span></div>

                        <div class = 'content'><span class = 'textBuffer'>The new self-serve, cash-and-carry concept of grocery retailing is a big hit with customers, who take advantage of quality goods at lower prices. Within a decade, the Loblaw chain expands to more than 70 stores in Ontario alone.</span></div>

                    </div>
                                            ........

</div>
</div>
```

So, when this `number>1000px`  the animation seems cycling the whole items from the begging again, until is going to get in right position

I am not sure if 1000px makes the problem, or it is a coincidence.

Did somebody ever seen that kind of problem and if it is possible to fix it. Or I have kill this 'animate' ?

Thanks !

Comment: If it works fine on 1.5.2 why are you trying to develop for older versions?

Comment: I cannot upgrade to 1.5.2, in my case, I have to use older version

Comment: @alexander , i don't think there is any problem with the version of jquery , its mostly some problem with your html or code...post your html also

Comment: @Alexander: Can you please provide a JSFiddle example and include approprite jQuery version, so we can see what's going on.

Comment: yes , I do, problem is that it works fine in 1.5.2 version of the jquery

Comment: just a quick not that you dont need to specify the `'px'` for the `left` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem, it is jQuery core bug, it has limitation on animate, 10000px.

It is easy to fix, just add or change this part of the code:

```
$.fx.prototype.cur = function(){ // we are overwriting this function to remove limiting of the size of the

    if ( this.elem[this.prop] != null && (!this.elem.style || this.elem.style[this.prop] == null) ) {
      return this.elem[ this.prop ];
    }

    var r = parseFloat( jQuery.css( this.elem, this.prop ) );
    return typeof r == 'undefined' ? 0 : r;

}
```